# Pandas dataframe rounding values in columns

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm reading a .csv file into a pandas dataframe like:

```
tempDF = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('file.csv')
```

one of the columns of the .csv file has values:

```
Val
2500
2600
2700
2800
2900
3000
```

Is it possible to round this values when loading the .csv file? I would like the column to be:

```
Val
2.5
2.6
2.7
2.8
2.9
3.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `converters` option in [***`pd.read_csv`***](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

> converters : dict, default None
>   Dict of functions for converting values in certain columns. Keys can either be integers or column labels

```
tempDF = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('file.csv', converters=dict(Val=lambda x: x / 1000))
```

Comment: Getting the following TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Found the issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try casting the values to int using astype:

```
import pandas as pd

tempDF =  pd.read_csv('val.csv')
tempDF['Val_thousands'] = tempDF['Val'].astype(int) / 1000
```